# Regex to find the text without a special character

Tags: java, regex

I have a paragraph, in that, some of the texts are surrounded with a specific html tag. I need to to find the text which are not surrounded by that specific html tag.
For example

```html
AVG Antivirus for Smartphones and Tablets detects harmful apps and SMS. 

<font color='black'>AVG</font> Mobilation™ AntiVirus Pro for Android™ is a mobile security 

solution that helps protect your mobile device from viruses, malware, spyware and online 

exploitation in real-time. avg blah blah...
```

I want to find the word AVG (case insensitive) which is not surrounded by `<font color='black'> </font>`. It can be part the word or single whole word. In the case of part of the text, the whole word containing the word AVG should not surrounded by that html tag

How can I do it with Java?

Comment: You want to find that whole string, except the part that is surrounded by the font tag?  Or you just want to find whether the whole string contains the string "AVG" (not in a font tag)?

Comment: It may be a while string or part of the word, should not surrounded by the html font tag

Comment: you need to use negative lookbehind and nevative lookahead. see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and apply it to whatever regex engine you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind

You can try following in case you haven't already :-

```
(?<!<font color='black'>)AVG(?!</font>)
```